# How browser load web page?

Tags: browser, proxy

Does any body know how browser(IE, Firefox, Chrome) load web page? I think they first load the html and then the js, css, image. But I'm not sure. Any body know it for specific? Or can give me a reference? I'm doing a proxy server. I proxy all the data to the browser. But the browser is still loading the web page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a plugin such as Firebug in Firefox, or the built-in developer tools in Chrome. These will show you which files are loaded, in what order, and whether they are loaded from the browser cache or from the server. You *are* considering the impact of the browser cache in this, right?

With nothing in the cache, the browser will naturally load the page first, since it's the only way it can know what js, css and images to load.

*Edit*: as pointed out in other answers, the fact that it loads the page first doesn't mean that it's necessarily *done* with that before starting on the other resources; it may happen in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

This is implementation specific, and varies between browsers.
It's also one of the bottlenecks in web browsing, so there are various optimizations

- Some load all the resources from one server using the same connection, to avoid the overhead of opening new connections
- Some will start loading new resources in parallel, as soon as the link is encountered in the referring page, with out waiting for the page to be completely loaded or parsed

So if you're building a general purpose proxy you can't assume a specific methodology.

Comment: Does IE, FF, Chrome have a official reference for this?